# Soundpool and API33

Tags: android, soundpool, android-api-33

I'm trying to test my old apk with API33 emulator but sound doesn't work, up to API31 works well.

```
bt_sound = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_sound);      
bt_sound.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        soundPool.play(soundDrinn, volume, volume, 1, 0, 1f);}
});
```

LogCat pressing above button:

```
2023-09-02 16:19:29.966 379-4425/? E/android.hardware.audio@7.1-impl.ranchu: device/generic/goldfish/audio/talsa.cpp:mixerGetOrOpenImpl:58 failure: nullptr
2023-09-02 16:19:29.966 379-4425/? E/android.hardware.audio@7.1-impl.ranchu: pcmOpen:169 pcm_open failed for nChannels=2 sampleRateHz=48000 period_count=4 period_size=1056 isOut=1 with cannot open device (0) for card (0): No such file or directory
2023-09-02 16:19:29.966 379-4425/? E/android.hardware.audio@7.1-impl.ranchu: device/generic/goldfish/audio/talsa.cpp:pcmOpen:172 failure: nullptr
2023-09-02 16:19:29.966 379-4425/? E/android.hardware.audio@7.1-impl.ranchu: device/generic/goldfish/audio/device_port_sink.cpp:create:228 failure: nullptr
```